# UDPServer does not receive the sent data from the UDPClient

Tags: java, network-programming, udp, client-server

I have the following  UDP client and servcer classes and I am trying to send some string from the `UDPClient` to the another class 'UDPServer' in the same java project at the localhost and port 7777. I am facing problem that I am not receiving anything in the UDPServer class from the UDPClient class. Does anyone have an idea where the problem is?

I appreciate any help!

**UDPClient**

```
import java.net.DatagramPacket;
import java.net.DatagramSocket;
import java.net.InetAddress;


class UDPClient {

    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
        String aString = "Hello World";
        DatagramSocket clientSocket = new DatagramSocket();
        InetAddress IPAddress = InetAddress.getByName("localhost");
        byte[] sendData = new byte[1024];
        byte[] receiveData = new byte[1024];
        sendData = aString.getBytes();
        DatagramPacket sendPacket = new DatagramPacket(sendData, sendData.length, IPAddress, 7777);
        clientSocket.send(sendPacket);
        DatagramPacket receivePacket = new DatagramPacket(receiveData, receiveData.length);
        clientSocket.receive(receivePacket);
        String modifiedSentence = new String(receivePacket.getData());
        System.out.println("FROM SERVER:" + modifiedSentence);
        clientSocket.close();
    }
}
```

**UDPServer**

```
import java.net.DatagramPacket;
import java.net.DatagramSocket;
import java.net.InetAddress;


class UDPServer {

        public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
            DatagramSocket serverSocket = new DatagramSocket(7777);
            byte[] receiveData = new byte[1024];
            byte[] sendData = new byte[1024];
            while (true) {
                DatagramPacket receivePacket = new DatagramPacket(receiveData, receiveData.length);
                serverSocket.receive(receivePacket);
                String sentence = new String(receivePacket.getData());
                System.out.println("RECEIVED: " + sentence);
                InetAddress IPAddress = receivePacket.getAddress();
                int port = receivePacket.getPort();
                String capitalizedSentence = sentence.toUpperCase();
                sendData = capitalizedSentence.getBytes();
                DatagramPacket sendPacket = new DatagramPacket(sendData, sendData.length, IPAddress, port);
                serverSocket.send(sendPacket);
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: any exception on your datagram server?

Comment: @Sonor No I am not getting any error or any exception.

Comment: The code seems to work as intended on my machine

Comment: I don't see any problem visibly

Comment: @scsere: have not you changed anything at the code? have you used the same port?

Comment: @water Yep, copy-pasted the code... You could try to replace `InetAddress.getByName("localhost");` with `InetAddress.getLocalHost();` in case it doesn't resolve properly on your machine

Comment: Your setup is not clear. What do you mean by same java project? Do the server and client run as two separate applications? If not, you cannot run two main classes within the same java application, so your problem might simply be that your server is not running at all.

Comment: Thanks! That was the answer :)

Answer (score 1):

Hi try to check what wrong with port allocation, because you code works ok.

Start your server and run this command:

Windows

```
 netstat -aon | FINDSTR 7777
```

Linux:

```
 netstat -aon | grep 7777
```

You should see the PID check if pid is same as UDPServer runs on. Also check firewall maybe there is something wrong?

Comment: If you can control your firewall, temporarily disable the whole firewall.  If that fixes your problem, you need to create firewall rules to all the server receive incoming data.  The Client should be able to send data out through the firewall without any problems.